# TableView row removal with NSFetchedResultsController crashing?

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to let users delete a row from a `UITableView` that's populated using a `NSFetchedResultsController` but keep getting a fatal error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I'm deleting the core data entry and then deleting the row in the tableView in my code but still get the error above:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.feedTable.beginUpdates()
        let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as Event
        self.managedObjectContext.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {}
        self.feedTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.feedTable.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Can anybody help understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to delete first from the table and than from the core data.

Comment: Doesn't work. :(

Comment: same error as before?

Comment: yep, unfortunately

Comment: ok remove beginUpdates and endUpdates and delete and than just reload the table and see whether it solves the issue or not?

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

If you use a fetched results controller. Only delete the object with

```
self.managedObjectContext.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
```

Try this solution

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let event = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as Event
        self.managedObjectContext.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {}

    }
}
```

You don't need `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`